# expected 1 bytes but received 3

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit

Getting this error while calling the following api. https://uhunt.onlinejudge.org/api/uname2uid/felix_halim

I am using retrofit. Getting same types of error. Like:

1. expected 1 bytes but received 3
2. expected 6 bytes but received 8
3. expected 3 bytes but received 5

Some part of my code is given below.

**Api Interface**

```
public interface UHApi {
    @GET("uname2uid/{userName}")
    Observable<Integer> loadUserId(
            @Path("userName") String userName
    );
}
```

**Retrofit Insrance**

```
public class RetrofitInstance {

    private static Retrofit INSTANCE;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://uhunt.onlinejudge.org/api/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (RetrofitInstance.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**Api Call**

```
UHApi mUHApi;
mUHApi = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(UHApi.class);

mUHApi.loadUserId("felix_halim")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"onSubscribe called");
                        compositeDisposable.add(d);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer userId) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onNext called");
                        Log.e(TAG, "user id = " + userId);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError called");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError msg = " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Pretty unclear where you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets in the end point are used when you define it within path annotation. For the Query annotation, you need not add the brackets and what's within it.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post. Actually I have tried with Path annotation. While posting it, I have used Query annotation. Actually, it would be Path annotation.

Comment: looking at the pattern of bytes, I see they are increased by two for every expected result. The URL you are hitting is not a json but a string instead. Can you try making it as a json and checking it out as you're adding GSON converter factory.

Comment: Instead of using Integer I have tried with String, Integer, Long, Byte, ArrayList<String>, JsonObject, JsonArray. But the error remains same.

Comment: Let me build a dummy project and I'll get back to you with the working code. You need response as 339, right?

Comment: Yes. I need response 339. Thanks in advance.